# Repeating variable name in forest function

Tags: r, meta, r-forestplot

I have a column that displays the author name and year in my forest plot. There are some cases where the same author name and year repeats and r is automatically adding a serial number at the end:

Barrera et al., 2013.1
Barrera et al., 2013.2

Is there a way to remove this automatic serial number?

Comment: please add a small, self-contained, reproducible example

Comment: Please make it easier for people who are trying to help you. Don’t add data/code as images. Provide a reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).